# Defining routes and controllers relationship for given pages

Tags: php, mvc, controller, url-routing

I'm building a CMS app with the help of a custom framework. The back-office is composed of the following pages:

- post list
- page list
- user list
- post edit
- page edit
- user edit

Actually, my routes are defined as follows (I don't put regex here for clarity sake):

```
return array(
    '/post-list/' => array(
        'controller' => 'PostListController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    '/page-list/' => array(
        'controller' => 'PageListController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    '/user-list/' => array(
        'controller' => 'UserListController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    '/post-edit/(params)' => array(
        'controller' => 'PostEditController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    '/page-edit/(params)' => array(
        'controller' => 'PageEditController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
    '/user-edit/(params)' => array(
        'controller' => 'UserEditController',
        'action'     => 'view'
    ),
);
```

With this approach, there are many little controllers that share almost the same lines of code (not DRY code). For example:

#### PostListController:

```
public function view()
{
    $postMapper = $this->repository->getMapper('PostMapper');
    $postSlugs  = $postMapper->fetchPostSlugs();
    $posts = array();

    foreach ($postSlugs as $postSlug) {
        $posts[] = $this->repository->getModel('PostModel', $postSlug);
    }

    if ($view = $this->repository->getView('PostListView')) {
        $models = array('posts' => $posts);
        $body   = $view->render($models);

        $this->response->setBody($body);
        $this->response->send();

        return;
    }
    // ...404 handling
}
```

... will be nearly identical to the `PageListController`, the only things that change are View and Model class names.

What would be the MVC best practice or which make more sense?

1. Keeping this approach: 1 controller for 1 page?
2. Making a controller that handles **Lists** having for action: `posts()`, `pages()`, `users()` and a controller handling **Edit** the same way?
3. Making a controller handling **Post** having for actions: `edit()` and `list()`, same for **Page** and **User**? (note that in this case I might still have some "unDRY" code).
4. Something else..?

Comment: could you make a parent class or a trait to abstract out the common functionality for those controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself today again the same question for my current project where I have to implement a bunch of entities that will need their own controllers implementing usual actions such as:

- `show()`
- `list()`
- `edit()`
- `save()`
- `delete()`
- etc...

I believe we can extract from each of these actions a logic/control flow pattern common to all entities.

Thus, an abstract `EntityController` implementing these actions seems to me the way to go... Of course we can inject in child controllers extending `EntityController` specific parameters and services.